# Android Browser

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am building a website which needs to be views on the Android browser as well.

I heard that on the android browser the javascript seems to be breaking. I do not have an android device to view it for myself.

Are there an emulators for the android browser that I can download and check for myself.

My Dev Env: MAC (Lion).

Comment: And it is a good advice to do the final checks on a working android phone, because the emulator is, especially concerning speed, not equal to a real device.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the emulator you need to have the android sdk installed: instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html). Then you can look at using the Android emulator docs by Google: [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html)

Another option is to run your own VM of android using parrallels, vmware, etc. The information for that and downloads can be found [here](http://android-x86.org/)